Fetch data from refcursor in postgresql
I have a SQL function that returns refcursor as an out parameter. How can I fetch data after calling that function?
I can successfully call the function like: select data_out from get_data_by_id('5482100'). Here data_out is a refcursor. I tried: fetch next from (select data_out from get_data_by_ids('5482100')) but it gives me an error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: fetch next from (select data_out from get_data_by_ids(...
                        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 17


if your function returns a refcursor as an OUT parameter:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data_by_id(p_id TEXT)
RETURNS refcursor AS
$$
DECLARE
    ref refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN ref FOR
    SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id = p_id;
    RETURN ref;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

use a combination of the DO block, cursor operations, and fetching data:
DO $$
DECLARE
    ref refcursor;
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- Call the function and get the refcursor
    ref := get_data_by_id('5482100');

    -- Fetch and display the data from the refcursor
    LOOP
        FETCH NEXT FROM ref INTO rec;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        -- Process the record (for example, printing it out)
        RAISE NOTICE '%', rec;
    END LOOP;

    -- Close the refcursor
    CLOSE ref;
END;
$$;

